# How to put several links on the same line?

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

My links unfortunately gets on different lines. I have tried to add display:inline;  in my css but it doesen't help at all

```
<h5>
    <a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Start </a>
    <a href="bildredigering.html" target="search_iframe">Bildredigering</a>
    <a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Foton</a>
    <a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Vector </a>
    <a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Om sidan</a>
</h5>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code???

Comment: Provide us with some code so we can offer some better help.

Comment: <h5><a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Start </a>
<a href="bildredigering.html" target="search_iframe">Bildredigering</a>
<a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Foton</a>
<a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Vector </a>
<a href="start.html" target="search_iframe">Om sidan</a>
</h5>

Comment: Are you trying to make a menu/navigation bar?

Comment: Yes that's my intention...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a {
float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5tzL42aq
I hope this will help...

Comment: If you have `<ul>` and `<li>`, why not just use it?

Comment: You're right that's indeed a better way. But she said several links so.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to make a menu bar. If that's what you want to do, then you would need to make an unordered list `<ul>` followed by `<li>` for every menu you want.

Here is an example:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a more in depth tutorial for that: [Menu bar tutorial](http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/)

You should definitely learn some more `HTML` and `CSS`. Here is a link to it: [Web Designing tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/)

**Update**

Here is a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6veeaafz/).

Comment: <ul>
<li><a href="start.html" target="search_iframe"><img src="sitepictures/n1.jpg" alt="Start"></a></li>
<li><a href="bildredigering.html" target="search_iframe"><img src="sitepictures/n2.jpg" alt="Bildredigering"></a></li>
<li><a href="start.html" target="search_iframe"><img src="sitepictures/n3.jpg" alt="Foton"></a></li>
<li><a href="start.html" target="search_iframe"><img src="sitepictures/n5.jpg" alt="Vector"></a></li>
<li><a href="start.html" target="search_iframe"><img src="sitepictures/n4.jpg" alt="Om sidan"></a></li>
</ul>

Comment: Did't meant to send it without comment. It don't give any effect

Comment: I tried but it got the same result, different lines.

Comment: Did you add the `css`?

Comment: My css is in a seperat file so i just removed the <h5>